# date: hours missed or incorrect if add "UTC" in the commands

Tags: bash, date, utc

Hi I want to use `date` in my bash script to update the calculation timing steps. Say if I have `YMDH=2017032522` (in UTC time zone) and I want to get the timing stamps after 12 hours (which should be `2017032610`, also in UTC time zone). And I tried following commands:

```
INC=+12hours
date +%Y%m%d -d "${YMDH::8} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00 UTC ${INC}"
```

Then I got results as `20170326`. It's obvious that the hours are not shown here. But if I tried with

```
INC=+12hours
date +%Y%m%d -d "20170325 22:00:00 UTC ${INC}"
```

I can got results of `2017032612`. The hours are shown here but it's wrong...I hope to get `2017032610` here.

I know that I can use `--debug` option here. So I tried with `date +%Y%m%d --debug -d "${YMDH::8} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00 UTC ${INC}"`, here is the logging information:

```
(base) $ date +%Y%m%d --debug -d "${YMDH::8} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00 UTC ${INC}"
date: parsed number part: (Y-M-D) 2017-03-25
date: parsed time part: 22:00:00
date: parsed relative part: +12 hour(s)
date: parsed zone part: UTC+00
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+00)
date: using specified time as starting value: '22:00:00'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2017-03-25 22:00:00 TZ=+00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2017-03-25 22:00:00 TZ=+00' = 1490479200 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+12 hours, +0 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1490522400 epoch-seconds
date: warning: daylight saving time changed after time adjustment
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1490522400.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-03-26 10:00:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-03-26 12:00:00 (UTC+02)
20170326
```

So is there anybody who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: convert everything to seconds since epoch.

Then, add seconds.

Then, convert back to the format you need **upon use**.

```
sec=$(date -ud "2017-03-25 22:00:00" +%s)
# I want to get the timing stamps after 12 hours
sec=$((sec + 12 * 60 *60))
# which should be 2017032610
date -ud "@$sec" +%Y%m%d%H
```

Comment: Thanks but how can start from ```${YYYYMMDDHH}```?

Comment: What do you think `"${YMDH::8} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00` does?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean how can I start from ```${YMDH}```...but now I got it, it should be ```sec=$(date -ud "${YMDH::8} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00" +%s)```, right? but here there is no ```UTC``` involved. Is that ok? Thanks!

Comment: So if you do  not know what `${var::}` does, here's documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion . `> right?` for example, I would do `${YMDH:0:2}-${YMDH:2:2}-${YMDH:4:2} ${YMDH:8:2}:00:00`. `> Is that ok?` I used `-u`.